# How to get correct DateSeparator in Delphi 5?

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I am trying to get the correct `DateSeparator` when the system locale  is set to Cenz Republic. The current date is formatted as `9.3.2017`, but `DateSeparator` is always `'/'` instead of `'.'`.  What can I do to get the correct date separator?

Comment: Can you show a little MVCE

Comment: my seetings : Control panel->Region and language-> format -> Czech Republic .  Now short date  format is d.M.yyyy here separator is . but when i put dateseparator in messagebox like Messagebox(dateseparator) ; and run it, it will display '/'(which is default separator of dateseparator) instead of '.' as separator

Comment: `DateSeparator` is initialized to whatever the user's current locale says it is, according to [`GetLocaleInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318101.aspx) for [`LOCALE_SDATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373837.aspx).

Comment: Since `DateSeparator` is a global variable in D5, it can be changed by some other part of your program.

Comment: [mcve] means someone has a much better chance of helping you. Of course if don't really want help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding date presentations there are several separate global variables affecting the output. You mention two of them:

```
`DateSeparator: Char;` (initialized from registry with reference `LOCALE_SDATE`)
`ShortDateFormat: string;` (initialized from registry with reference `LOCALE_SSHORTDATE`)
```

The other ones you can see in the documentation or in code in unit `SysUtils` starting on line 490 (in Delphi 7, might be different in Delphi 5).

Since the `DateSeparator` and `ShortDateFormat` are separate variables, it is possible that you see dates presented correctly according your locale, while the `DateSeparator` return an erroneous character.

To rectify, you can assign the correct character to `DateSeparator` yourself in your code, but beware if you are using 3rd party libraries, that those might possibly also want to change it.

Comment: `DateSeparator` is at line 465 of my antique D5 sysutils.  Good answer, +1

Comment: I don't think Delphi 5 supports functions taking a `TFormatSettings` record. Everything uses the shared global variables.

Comment: The question asks why the variable does not hold the expected value. That is what is being asked, and that is what an answer needs to speak to.

Comment: @David The question asks *How to get the correct date separator?* That, together with a why, is what I try to answer (currently verifying if my second point is rubbish)

Comment: @TomBrunberg:  I can't see an overload, nor any sign of TFormatSettings anywhere in the D5 source.  I guess TFormatSettings must have been a later addition.  In that era, myself I always used the SysTools date & time routines in preference to the built-in ones.  That was the only code, as I recall where there were no y2k worries.

Comment: Thank you @Martyn for digging into it. I remove the second point in my answer.

Comment: Note the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373837.aspx) for `LOCALE_SDATE`: "*Character(s) for the date separator. The maximum number of characters allowed for this string is four, including a terminating null character.  Windows Vista and later: **This constant is deprecated**. Use `LOCALE_SSHORTDATE` instead. A custom locale might not have a single, uniform separator character. For example, a format such as `"12/31, 2006"` is valid.*"